# How to keep Jquery gridview hover-menu visible

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I am creating a hover-menu on a gridview, but for some reasons, I cannot keep the popup visible. When the mouse is over the label, the popup shows up, but when i move it on the popup, it doesn't stay visible.

```
            $('.label').mouseover(function(e) {
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").show();
            });

            $('.label').mouseout(function(e) {
                $(e.target).closest("tr").find(".popup").hide();
            });

            $('.popup').mouseover(function(e) {
                $(e.target).show();
            });

            $('.popup').mouseout(function(e) {
                $(e.target).hide();
            });


<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:Label ID="label1" CssClass="label" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Column1") %>'></asp:Label>

            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="popup" CssClass="popup" 
            Style="display: none; position: absolute; margin-left: 60px; width: 250px;">


                Random text

            </asp:Panel>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Maybe the popup is hidden because even though the mouse is over it, it is outside the label? Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.label').mouseover(function (e) {
            $(this).find(".popup").show();
        });

        $('.label').mouseout(function (e) {
            $(this).find(".popup").hide();
        });
  });
```

Comment: run the project, in browser right click and view page source click that. can u paste that html code for one item template?

Comment: thanks, i had to replace $(e.target) with $(this) in the  $('.popup').mouseover(function()) and now it works fine :)